# How can I keep inputs from being "held over" to subsequent interactions?

Tags: bixby

My action has 3 inputs: required Book, optional Chapter, optional Verse.

If I said `read [book] [chapter] [verse]`, I get the correct response.

If I follow that up with `read [book] [chapter]`, I'm getting the Verse value passed in from the previous request. How do I keep that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass the issue (it appears), but creating three separate actions (required Book, required Book + required Chapter, required Book + required Chapter + required Verse).

Then, I just needed to duplicate my `action-endpoint` to allow the same endpoint to accept all three actions.

While I see the value of "historical inputs" in certain cases, seems like there should be a way to ignore them, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely do not want any historical inputs, you can experiment with making those concepts [transient](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/modeling.modeling-concepts#transient-concepts)

Comment: Transient is a concept feature (action outputs), not action inputs. I did try making the concept that was that particular action's output transient, just in case. No bueno.

Answer (score -1):

Bixby uses historical inputs (eg. inputs from previous requests) to fill in any missing inputs from a user's utterance as a way to provide a streamlined conversation flow.

In use cases such as your's where such assumptions should not be made, I would recommend using `prompt-behavior (AlwaysSelection)` in your Action's collect input definition. This would ensure that Bixby does not use historical input to fill in the gaps and, instead, asks the user for the input in question. You can read more about `prompt-behavior` [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input.prompt-behavior).

Comment: This changes the behavior by requiring the user to confirm or supply values. That would be undesired, even the `required Book` case (I don't want users to have to confirm every utterance)... definitely undesired in the `optional Verse` case (as it then becomes *required*).